# Linux CLI: List top level directories with zero files

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I need a list of top-level directories with zero files. Specifically, they can contain subdirectories provided they are empty. Here's what I've tried and the issues with each:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty
```

This does not show directories with subdirectories -- also with zero files.

It skips structures like the following:
Top-level-dir ( 0 files ) => 2nd-level dir ( 0 files )

```
find . -type f | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

The above line is great but it skips empty top-level directories containing subdirectories -- if those subdirs are empty as well. I should see all top-level directories in the output and I'm only seeing directories with files. I'm looking for a solution that will print directories with 0 files in addition to the file count of other top-level directories.

The correct solution will include top-level directories with 0 files -- even if they contain subdirectories, provided all subdirectories contain 0 files as well.

Example output:

- dir1 0
- dir2 5
- dir3 0
- dir4 26

...etc.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do this. You'll need to write a function that counts the number of files in a directory, then compare this with `0`.

Comment: Why do you use `.` instead of `/` when you need a list of top-level directories?

Comment: @Cyrus just the highest level in the `PWD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d \
  -exec sh -c 'echo -n "{}: "; find "{}" -type f -print | wc -l' \;
```

`find * -maxdepth 0 -type d` generates a list of top-level directories. For each directory, we run the command passed as the argument to `-exec`. In this command ,`{}` is substitute by the name of a directory.

Output will look something like:

```
./dir1: 0
./dir2: 2
./dir3: 33
./dir4: 0
./dir5: 62
```

Etc.